# How to know the exact loginname of the user who operates as system account?

Tags: spuser

If current logged user operates as "System Account", SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName will return "sharepoint\system", so I want to know the exact loginname of the user. Here is what I tried:

```
SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
if (user.LoginName.ToLower().Equals(@"sharepoint\system"))
{
    string loginName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    // do something...
}
```

It works fine at the begining, but I met a problem when I test it in "Claims-Based Authentication" webapplication, I found:

```
SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName =  sharepoint\system (The real loginname is i:0#.w|domain\user); 
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name = 0#.w|domain\user;
```

So, Why does HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name return "**0#.w|domain\user**" instead of "**i:0#.w|domain\user**"? How to get current user's loginname correctly? (I want to get "**i:0#.w|domain\user**")
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, non of your end users should really be logged in as system account, so I fail to see the problem. What is the objective of this?

Comment: @RobertLindgren Thanks for your information. It comes from a bug in our testing, we created an audience, and its rule is "Account Name = domain/currentuser", so if current user operates as system account, AudienceManager.IsMemberOfAudience will returns false, but it should return true actually. So, that's why I asked the question.

Comment: I recognize the situation :P I usally just hard code that "if system user: do this and that"

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
string userName = String.Empty;
SPClaimProviderManager mgr = SPClaimProviderManager.Local;
if(mgr != null)
{
   userName = mgr.DecodeClaim(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName).Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if current user operates as system account, the loginname is "sharepoint\system", your code will throw exception.

Answer (score 2):

This may be solve your purpose

http://sharepoint2010insight.blogspot.in/2010/11/sharepoint-2010-get-claim-username-and.html

http://practicalsharepoint2010.blogspot.in/2012/02/logged-in-username-sharepoint-2010.html

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Comment: Thanks, but it needs a correct loginname, in my situation, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name returns "0#.w|domain\user", which should be "i:0#.w|domain\user" actually. Do you know why? And SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName returns "sharepoint\system", which can not be decoded.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `GetUserIdentifierEncodedClaim` method documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.claims.spclaimprovidermanager.getuseridentifierencodedclaim(v=office.15).aspx).

```
SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
if (user.LoginName.ToLower().Equals(@"sharepoint\system"))
{
    IIdentity userIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
    string loginName = GetUserIdentifierEncodedClaim(userIdentity);
    // do something...
}
```

As to your other question, there doesn't appear to be a documented answer. This is just a guess, but `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` may not provide the full encoded value because here it can be assumed to be an identity claim, making the `i:` unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works in all claims provider scenario's like Forms Based Auth, Windows Auth). And it works for normal users and sharepoint\system accounts.

```
IClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as IClaimsPrincipal;
if (claimsPrincipal == null)
{
    return;
}

IClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (IClaimsIdentity)claimsPrincipal.Identity;
if (claimsIdentity == null)
{
    return;
}

var claims = claimsIdentity.Claims;
if (claims == null || !claims.Any())
{
    return;
}

Claim identityClaim = claims.Where(c => c.ClaimType == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).FirstOrDefault();
if (identityClaim == null)
{
    return;
}
return identityClaim.Value; \\ will return DOMAIN formatted user, or FBA username
```