# SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser; return wrong user

Tags: sharepoint-server

when execute this statement `SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser` it gives me user `SharePoint\system` and when I execute this statement

```
if (profileManager.UserExists(username))
                        { }
```

it says user not found.

I logged in with `SharePoint\spadmin`. why it is returning wrong user name.

Comment: `SharePoint\spadmin` in your case may be the app pool account and hence when you login it appears as `SharePoint\system` account.

Comment: but why profileManager.UserExists(username) returns false ?

Comment: Perhaps there may not be a profile associated with the system account. Check in the UPS if there is a profile for it.

Comment: yes there is account for spadmin but no system account. 

My question is from where the system account is coming in context and how can I change it to get spadmin account always ?

Comment: In SharePoint world, the app pool account is called the system account and hence when you login as `spadmin`, the context shows the current user as system account

Comment: right, system account have no profile and I cannot access spadmin profile from system account ? there is no way ?

Answer (score 2):

`SharePoint\spadmin` in your case may be the app pool account and hence when you login to SharePoint it appears as `SharePoint\system account`. In SharePoint world, the app pool account is called the `system account`.
To get the user name of the system account you can use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`
Check these for more information:

[Get current logged user name for user "Account operates as System"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43322/get-current-logged-user-name-for-user-account-operates-as-system)

[How to know the exact loginname of the user who operates as system account?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69492/how-to-know-the-exact-loginname-of-the-user-who-operates-as-system-account)

Comment: I fixed it using this statement. is this the correct way ?
                            username = new UserProfileManager(context).GetUserProfile(false).AccountName.ToString();

Comment: @MuhammadZaighum, I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one else suggested this before, I am leaving this suggestion here in hope it may help somebody.

Like Nadeem already suggested, getting **"SharePoint\system"** as the current logged user name in a site collection is probably an indication that the current user actually is the same the current web application associated application pool is running as.

For those reason when in doubt in the past I have used the following extension method.

```
public static string RealLoginName(this SPUser instance)
{
  if (!instance.LoginName.Equals("SHAREPOINT\\system", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
     return instance.LoginName;
  else return instance.ParentWeb.Site.WebApplication.ApplicationPool.Username;
}
```

There may be cases where you don't want to use the `SPUser` ParentWeb property (or you don't have an `SPUser` to begin with), but you get the general idea... just get old of the current `SPWebApplication` context and from here get the application pool running user1. username

Comment: +1, that is nice way of getting the username of system account.